# Merging a CSV file horizontally with PHP

Tags: php, csv

Hello so I'm just wondering if this is possible with PHP, so here is the scenario...

I have one CSV file example 'first.csv':

```
"Name","Age","Job"
"Peter Algarve","17","Mechanic"
"Will Smith","50","Actor"
```

And then I have this CSV 'second.csv':

```
"Origin","Eye Color","Birthday"
"Jamaica","Red","17-8-1967"
"USA","Brown","2-8-1969"
```

Now what I want to do is add the second CSV data to the end of the rows on the first CSV like so:

```
"Name","Age","Job","Origin","Eye Color","Birthday"
"Peter Algarve","17","Mechanic","Jamaica","Red","17-8-1967"
"Will Smith","50","Actor","USA","Brown","2-8-1969"
```

Notice how I also needed to add a comma to separate the new columns, is there any way that this can be done in PHP?

Comment: Yes, lots of ways. How big are the files? Are the lines always in the correct order? Did you try anything that failed?

Comment: read both csvs into arrays (e.g. `fgetcsv()`, then push the elements of one array's records into the corresponding records of the other array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a csv of the merged output, there is no need to read all the data into memory, you can just read, merge and write line by line:

```
$fileOneHandle     = fopen('first.csv', 'r');
$fileTwoHandle     = fopen('second.csv', 'r');
$fileMergedHandle  = fopen('merged.csv', 'w');

while($fileOneLine = fgetcsv($fileOneHandle) && $fileTwoLine = fgetcsv($fileTwoHandle)){
    fputcsv($fileMergedHandle, array_merge($fileOneLine, $fileTwoLine));
}

fclose($fileOneHandle);
fclose($fileTwoHandle);
fclose($fileMergedHandle);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read each file into an array with `file()`

```
$first = file('firstFile.csv');
$second = file ('secondFile.csv');
```

Iterate over the arrays and construct a new one, concatenating the two lines, separated by a comma
and using `trim()` to get rid of any new line characters we might have picked up along the way.

```
foreach ($first as $i=>$row){
    $result[$i] = trim($row) . "," . trim($second[$i]);
}
```

Write the resulting array into a new csv file

```
$fp = fopen('result.csv', 'w');

foreach ($result as $line) {
    fputcsv($fp, $line);
}

fclose($fp);
```

Doing `print_r($result)` will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => "Name","Age","Job","Origin","Eye Color","Birthday"
    [1] => "Peter Algarve","17","Mechanic","Jamaica","Red","17-8-1967"
    [2] => "Will Smith","50","Actor","USA","Brown","2-8-1969"
)
```